# iOS(Swift) App hangs after calling a struct's static var

Tags: ios, swift, static, freeze, nsobject

So I've got a subclass of an NSObject in which I implemented this:

```
struct SharedStruct {
    static var sharedInstance = TaskCoordinator()
}
class var sharedInstance:TaskCoordinator {
    get { return SharedStruct.sharedInstance }
    set { SharedStruct.sharedInstance = newValue }
}
```

When I call this anywhere, the App hangs without an error. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some kind of loop, did you halt the execution and look at the stack?

Comment: Ouh yeah, called the instance before initialising it, thanks!